# Which EL Resolver will be used for @ManagedBeans from library?

Tags: jsf, el

I'm considering moving some of the `@ManagedBeans` to the library to reuse them in other projects. However, I couldn't find information which **EL Resolver** will be used then.

The project with shared beans must have own `faces-config.xml`, so it is possible to declare EL resolver then. Will that resolver be used, or that from the application using that beans? And what if EL resolver is not defined in library jar?

Comment: Why do you need to declare an EL resolver?

Comment: To inject dependencies